# control characters in C Buffer

Tags: c, linux, ascii

I need to transmit the following content over socket.

```
^ASO00^D
```

I tried to store them in buffer:

```
unsigned char fileData[] = {'^A','S','O','0','0','^D'},
```

when I print the fileData, it doesn't print the ASCII Characters.

```
 printf("%s\n", fileData);
```

It only prints "S000".

How can I save the control characters in buffer

But when I store this in a file and read it from the file, the control characters gets printed

Comment: By `^A` I assume you're meaning what is known as "control-A" which corresponds to the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) control character `SOH`? If I then tell you that `^B` corresponds to `STX` I'm sure you will be able to figure out what `^D` should be.

Comment: Yes. Exactly SOH

Comment: `'^A'` -> `1`, `'^D'` -> `4`

Comment: `'^A'` is multi-character character constant, whose value is implementation-defined.

Comment: `^A` is a conventional way to write ASCII `SOH` - in C, we write it as `\001`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised this compiles... It certainly throws warnings on my system, and I see "`ASO00D`" printed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
        unsigned char fileData[] = {'^A','S','O','0','0','^D'};

        printf("%s\n", fileData);
}
```

```
$ gcc x.c -o x -Wall
x.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main(void) {
      ^
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:4:30: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  unsigned char fileData[] = {'^A','S','O','0','0','^D'};
                              ^
x.c:4:30: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
x.c:4:51: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  unsigned char fileData[] = {'^A','S','O','0','0','^D'};
                                                   ^
x.c:4:51: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
$ ./x
ASO00D
```

Don't forget to use `-Wall` and read the warnings - they are helpful!

`^A` is not a printable character, thus `printf()` (or more correctly your terminal) will not render it correctly, even if this had worked as you expected.

Also, as pointed out by Michael Walz in the comments, you should always terminate a string with a nul character - `\0`. In the above example you risk running past the end of the array, and thus *undefined behaviour*.

---

What you are actually trying to use is the common human-readable notation for control characters.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is typically printed as `^A`.

This doesn't mean you can put `^A` into a C character and expect it to work - for a start it's two characters... `^` and `A`.

Instead, you should refer to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and understand that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> actually modify the key pressed. *[I'm not referring to the keyboard scancodes]*.

```
 a  0x61  0b01100001
 A  0x41  0b01000001
^A  0x01  0b00000001
```

- Pressing <kbd>A</kbd> produces an `a` (`0x61`)
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> produces an `A` (`0x61 & ~0x20 = 0x41`)
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> produces a `^A` (`0x61 & ~0x60 = 0x01`)

Try instead using this:

```c
unsigned char fileData[] = {0x01,'S','O','0','0',0x04,'\0'};
```

However, even this will not `printf()` "*correctly*".

Try instead using a loop, like this: (note the `isprint()` and `iscntrl()` tests)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main(void) {
        int i;
        unsigned char fileData[] = {0x01,'S','O','0','0',0x04,'\0'};

        printf("%s\n", fileData);

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fileData) - 1; i++) {
                printf("%3d: 0x%02X   ", i, fileData[i]);
                if (isprint(fileData[i])) {
                        printf("%c", fileData[i]);
                } else if (iscntrl(fileData[i])) {
                        printf("^%c", fileData[i] + 'A' - 1);
                } else {
                        printf(".");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

```
$ gcc x.c -o x -Wall
x.c:4:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main(void) {
      ^
$ ./x
SO00
  0: 0x01   ^A
  1: 0x53   S
  2: 0x4F   O
  3: 0x30   0
  4: 0x30   0
  5: 0x04   ^D
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store byte values in an array:

```
unsigned char fileData[] = {0x01,'S','O','0','0',0x04},
```

Comment: It didn't worked.. Writing to file it added those characters but not when printing on the screen

Comment: @md.jamal you cannot `printf` control codes (ASCII codes < 32) and expect to get an output like `^A`.